# Nuxt fetch hook api can't access the api folder

Tags: api, vue.js, plugins, axios, nuxt.js

I have an api that I call in my `fetch()` hook:

pages/pageOne.vue:

```
  async fetch() {
    const { store, error } = this.$nuxt.context;
    try {
      await store.dispatch("folderOne/apiOne", null, { root: true });
    } catch (e) {
      error({
        message: "error"
      });
    }
  }
```

then in my store I have `apiOne` action setup like this:

store/folderOne/index.js:

```
//importing the api file here
const actions = {
   apiOne({ commit }) {
    apiFile.apiOne().then(data => {
        if(data && data.status === 200){
          // then commit
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
}
```

Then I have a file for my APIs setup like this:

api/apiFile.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

const httpClient = axios.create({
  headers: {
    key: 'value
  }
});

const baseUrl = process.env.config.baseUrl;

export default {
  apiOne() {
    return httpClient.get(`${baseUrl}values);
  },
}
```

It doesn't work. But when I call the same `apiOne` in a `@click` method it works. Anyone knows what's is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you see when you log the URL in `apiOne()`?

Answer (score 0):

your store is and should be a global construct of your application.
it means when you call for a action and your setup is correct, you don't have to handle directives/folders by yourself.

in your case all you should do is dispatch the action in your component like this:

```js
async fetch() {
    const { store, error } = this.$nuxt.context;
    try {
      await store.dispatch("apiOne", null, { root: true });
    } catch (e) {
      error({
        message: "error"
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: if this doesn't work please provide more informations like how are your store configs etc.

Comment: thanks, but that def is not the issue. 1- I have several store files. 2- I can call the api and it works if I call the api directly from store without using `apiFile.js` like:


const actions = {
   async apiOne({ commit }) {
   await axios
      .get(
        '${baseUrl} values',
        {
          headers: {
            key: "value"
          }
        }
      ).then() ...

The problem seems to be `fetch()` not accessing the `apiFile.js`